# Detect actual charset encoding in UTF

Tags: encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

Need good tool to detect encoding of the strings using some kind of mapping or heuristic method.

For example String: `áÞåàÐÝØÒ ÜÝÞÓÞ ßàØÛÞÖÕÝØÙ Java, ÜÞÖÝÞ ×ÐÝïâì Òáî ÔÞáâãßÝãî ßÐÜïâì`

Expected: `сохранив много приложений Java, можно занять всю доступную память`

The encoding is "ISO8859-5". When I'am trying to detect it with the below libs the result is "UTF-8". It is obviously that string was saved in utf, but is there any heuristic way using symbols mapping to analyse the characters and match them with the correct encoding?

Used usual encoding detect libs:

```
- enca (aptitude install enca)
- chardet (aptitude install chardet)
- uchardet (aptitude install uchardet)
- http://tika.apache.org/
- http://npmjs.com/package/detect-encoding
- libencode-detect-perl
- http://www-archive.mozilla.org/projects/intl/UniversalCharsetDetection.html
- http://jchardet.sourceforge.net/
- http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.googlecode.juniversalchardet/juniversalchardet/1.0.3/
- http://lxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/extensions/universalchardet/src/
- http://userguide.icu-project.org/
- http://site.icu-project.org
```

Comment: It's rather unclear what the situation is exactly. Your initial string "áÞåàÐÝØÒ.." is *apparently* the result of misinterpreting a blob of bytes using the wrong encoding. Therefore it's unclear what *"The encoding is "ISO8859-5""* is supposed to mean exactly. Any heuristic tool would not be analysing "the characters", it would need to look at the *bytes*, try all possible encodings, and then decide which encoding is most likely the right one for these bytes, since the character interpretation seems to make the most statistical sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to unwrap the UTF-8 encoding and *then* pass it to a character-encoding detection library.

If random 8-bit data is encoded into UTF-8 (assuming an identity mapping, i.e. a C4 byte is assumed to represent U+00C4, as is the case with ISO-8859-1 and its superset Windows 1252), you end up with something like

```
Source:  8F    0A 20 FE    65
Result:  C2 8F 0A 20 C3 BE 65
```

(because the UTF-8 encoding of U+008F is C2 8F, and U+00FE is C3 BE).  You need to revert this encoding in order to obtain the source string, so that you can then identify its character encoding.

In Python, something like

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import chardet

mystery = u'áÞåàÐÝØÒ ÜÝÞÓÞ ßàØÛÞÖÕÝØÙ Java, ÜÞÖÝÞ ×ÐÝïâì Òáî ÔÞáâãßÝãî ßÐÜïâì'
print chardet.detect(mystery.encode('cp1252'))
```

Result:

```
{'confidence': 0.99, 'encoding': 'ISO-8859-5'}
```

On the Unix command line,

```
vnix$ echo 'áÞåàÐÝØÒ ÜÝÞÓÞ ßàØÛÞÖÕÝØÙ Java, ÜÞÖÝÞ ×ÐÝïâì Òáî ÔÞáâãßÝãî ßÐÜïâì' |
> iconv -t cp1252 | chardet
<stdin>: ISO-8859-5 (confidence: 0.99)
```

or `iconv -t cp1252 file | chardet` to decode a file and pass it to `chardet`.

(For this to work successfully at the command line, you need to have your environment properly set up for transparent Unicode handling.  I am assuming that your shell, your terminal, and your locale are adequately configured.  Try a recent Ubuntu Live CD or something if your regular environment is stuck in the 20th century.)

In the general case, you cannot know that the incorrectly applied encoding is [CP 1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) but in practice, I guess it's going to be correct (as in, yield correct results for this scenario) most of the time.  In the worst case, you would have to loop over all available legacy 8-bit encodings and try them all, then look at the one(s) with the highest confidence rating from `chardet`.  Then, the example above will be more complex, too -- the mapping from legacy 8-bit data to UTF-8 will no longer be a simple identity mapping, but rather involve a translation table as well (for example, a byte F5 might correspond arbitrarily to U+0092 or whatever).

(Incidentally, `iconv -l` spits out a long list of aliases, so you will get a lot of fundamentally identical results if you use that as your input.  But here is a quick ad-hoc attempt at fixing your slightly weird Perl script.

```
#!/bin/sh
iconv -l |
grep -F -v -e UTF -e EUC -e 2022 -e ISO646 -e GB2312 -e 5601 |
while read enc; do
    echo 'áÞåàÐÝØÒ ÜÝÞÓÞ ßàØÛÞÖÕÝØÙ Java, ÜÞÖÝÞ ×ÐÝïâì Òáî ÔÞáâãßÝãî ßÐÜïâì' |
    iconv -f utf-8 -t "${enc%//}" 2>/dev/null |
    chardet | sed "s%^[^:]*%${enc%//}%"
done |
grep -Fwive ascii -e utf -e euc -e 2022 -e None |
sort -k4rn
```

The output still contains a lot of chaff, but once you remove that, the verdict is straightforward.

It makes no sense to try any multi-byte encodings such as UTF-16, ISO-2022, GB2312, EUC_KR etc in this scenario.  If you convert a string into one of these successfully, then the result will most definitely be *in* that encoding.  This is outside the scope of the problem outlined above: a string converted from an 8-bit encoding into UTF-8 using the wrong translation table.

The ones which returned `ascii` definitely did something wrong; most of them will have received an empty input, because `iconv` failed with an error.  In a Python script, error handling would be more straightforward.)

Comment: Very good! Thanks! Posted the results a bit below. Actually I see interesting results when iterating over all available iconv encodings.

Comment: ```$ iconv -l | tr "//" " " | perl -ne 'chomp $_; `echo "áÞåàÐÝØÒ ÜÝÞÓÞ ßàØÛÞÖÕÝØÙ Java, ÜÞÖÝÞ ×ÐÝïâì Òáî ÔÞáâãßÝãî ßÐÜïâì" | iconv -t $_ | chardet` =~ /<stdin>:\s*([^\s]+)\s*\(confidence:\s*([\d\.]+)\)/; if($1 && $2) { print "$2\t$1\n"; }' 2>/dev/null | sort | uniq | sort -k 1,1 -n -r | head -n 10```

Comment: 1.00    UTF-32LE
1.00    UTF-16LE
1.00    ascii
0.99    utf-8
0.99    ISO-8859-5
0.99    ISO-2022-KR
0.99    ISO-2022-JP
0.99    IBM866
0.99    EUC-TW
0.68    ISO-8859-7

Comment: Trying to convert ```echo 'ÀÐÑÞâÐ' | iconv -f ISO-8859-5 -t utf-8``` Gets ```УУУУУЂУ``` Must be ```Работа```

Comment: Well, yes, if you convert the string into EUC_KR then the result will most definitely *be* an EUC_KR string.  You should restrict to 8-bit encodings (multi-byte encodings can be identified somewhat more reliably in the first place anyway).  I'll update the answer to clarify this.

Comment: You want `echo 'ÀÐÑÞâÐ' | iconv -f utf-8 -t cp1252 | iconv -f ISO-8859-5 -t UTF-8`.  The string is a UTF-8 string which needs to be converted *to* the original 8-bit encoding first, then properly decoded back into UTF-8.

Comment: I cannot convert the test string into [IBM866](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_866).  With `echo 'áÞåàÐÝØÒ ÜÝÞÓÞ ßàØÛÞÖÕÝØÙ Java, ÜÞÖÝÞ ×ÐÝïâì Òáî ÔÞáâãßÝãî ßÐÜïâì' | iconv -f utf-8 -t ibm866` I get `iconv: illegal input sequence at position 0`.  But if it had been successful, I suppose it would just have been proof that in the end, you need human inspection to sort things out.

Comment: Ah, the IBM866 result comes with `iconv -t WINDOWS-936` which seems to be a [variant of GB2312](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_936).

Comment: Thanks! I've just finished with "native2ascii" tool from JDK. The results is ok. I'll try your solution also. Then will post the final results.

Comment: ```you need human inspection to sort things out``` this is not necessary. If iconv fails to convert string it return non-zero exit status. I.e. the selected encoding must be skipped.

Comment: There are many technically invalid decodings which can be dismissed without human intervention, like you say, but there are also many technically valid decodings which cannot. Then you do need human judgment.

Comment: Maybe also try https://github.com/LuminosoInsight/python-ftfy

Answer (score 0):

The string

`сохранив много приложений Java, можно занять всю доступную память`

is encoded in ISO8859-5 as bytes

`E1 DE E5 E0 D0 DD D8 D2 20 DC DD DE D3 DE 20 DF E0 D8 DB DE D6 D5 DD D8 D9 20 4A 61 76 61 2C 20 DC DE D6 DD DE 20 D7 D0 DD EF E2 EC 20 D2 E1 EE 20 D4 DE E1 E2 E3 DF DD E3 EE 20 DF D0 DC EF E2 EC`

The string

`áÞåàÐÝØÒ ÜÝÞÓÞ ßàØÛÞÖÕÝØÙ Java, ÜÞÖÝÞ ×ÐÝïâì Òáî ÔÞáâãßÝãî ßÐÜïâì`

is encoded in ISO-8859-1 as bytes

`E1 DE E5 E0 D0 DD D8 D2 20 DC DD DE D3 DE 20 DF E0 D8 DB DE D6 D5 DD D8 D9 20 4A 61 76 61 2C 20 DC DE D6 DD DE 20 D7 D0 DD EF E2 EC 20 D2 E1 EE 20 D4 DE E1 E2 E3 DF DD E3 EE 20 DF D0 DC EF E2 EC`

Look familiar?  They are the same bytes, just interpreted differently by different charsets.

Any tool that would look at these bytes would not be able to tell you the charset automatically, as they are perfectly valid bytes in both charsets.  You would have to tell the tool which charset to use when interpreting the bytes.

Any tool that tells you this particular byte sequence is encoded as UTF-8 is **wrong**.  These are NOT valid UTF-8 bytes.

Comment: That's not how I understand the question.  My interpretation is that the text was mistakenly encoded from ISO-8859-1 into UTF-8 although the source encoding (obviously) was not ISO-8859-1, ending up with bogus UTF-8 text.